# Ubuntu Route Audio Through Ladspa Plugin Then Skype/Application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, input-device

In ubuntu, how would I route my audio input through a ladspa plugin, then into an application? I guess this would be something like making a virtual audio input which was a ladspa host, then set that as the input to skype or whichever application? I want to sound like a robot with a pitch perfect singing ;)

Thanks in advance, ell.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't really have any knowledge about this but I'm pretty sure this may help you

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#Using_mbeq

The Archlinux wiki is the best place for ALL linux help, not only Arch!

Comment: This looks promising! I will try it in the morning.

Comment: @ell The only parts you should need to think about changing in that setup (other than the plugin of course) is routing the output, which this doesn't really describe how to do apart from to a hardware/software mixer, but it shouldn't be too hard to accomplish!